# Constructing segments

Tags: geometry

Draw a segment and label it $\overline{AB}$. Using only a compass and a straightedge, construct segment $\overline{CD}$ such that $CD=5\frac {1}{4}$ of $AB$. Explain and then justify your construction.

---

I don't know where to begin on constructing. I'm wondering if there is a simple and elegant way of approaching this problem!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Take the midpoint $M$ of $AB$ and the midpoint $N$ of $MB$.
 If $C$ is the symmetric of $N$ with respect to $B$, $\,AC=\frac{5}{4}AB$ as wanted.

Comment: $\frac{5}{4}$ or $5\frac {1}{4}$

Comment: @Thomas: oh, I see, maybe in OP's question $5\frac{1}{4}$ means $5+\frac{1}{4}$. In that case, the above construction can be easily adapted.

Comment: Yes, the original problem meant $\frac {21}{4}$.

Answer (score 1):

We will show that given $1, a, b$ we can construct $ab$. Draw a line $AD$ such that $AB=1$ and $AD=a$, then draw any other line through $A$ such that $C$ is a point on it and $AC=b$. Draw $DE$ parallel to $BC$ then clearly $AE=ab$. 
[image]

In your question $a$ is given and $b=5\frac14$ is construct-able from $1$.